# Variational quantum eigensolver in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I have implemented a hybrid quantum NN on a dataset to perform classification. Now I want to apply quantum PCA to my dataset to find the eigenvalues. After going through a few qiskit tutorials, I found that VQE is used for finding eigenvalues in qiskit. Is there a demo program implementing VQE on a dataset where we can check the steps?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the ibm quantum summer schools github repo they had a good notebook for step by step implementation of VQE and QAOA but the thing is that I do not think you can actually use that for finding eigen values. I am gonna recommend implementing QPCA from scartch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qiskit textbook [chapter on VQE](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html) is specific to molecule ground state, though it has a good introduction on what VQE is and how it works.

The [Qiskit Tutorial on Minimum Eigen Optimizer](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/optimization/3_minimum_eigen_optimizer.html), also available in [Quantum Lab](https://lab.quantum-computing.ibm.com/) where you can interactively play with it, should be good to get you going.